# Calculate spectral irradiance from electric and magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Consider an EM field $(\vec{E}(\vec{r},t),\vec{B}(\vec{r},t))$. I would like to determine the spectral irradiance ($\mathrm{W}/\mathrm{m}^2/\mathrm{Hz}$) of a surface receiving the field. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiance), it is  defined as $E_{e,\nu}(\vec{r},\nu)=\dfrac{\partial\langle\vec{S}\rangle}{\partial\nu}(\vec{r},\nu)\vec{n}$ where $\vec{S}$ is the Poynting vector and $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector to the surface. So here's my question:

I know that $\vec{S}(\vec{r},t)=\dfrac{\vec{E}(\vec{r},t)\times\vec{B}(\vec{r},t)}{\mu_0}$, but how is defined $\langle\vec{S}\rangle(\vec{r},\nu)$ (by using $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$)?

Answer (score 0):

$\left < S \right >$ is the time average of the Poynting vector. One way of defining time-average for any oscillating quantity $A$ (with a period $T$) is:
$$\left < A \right > = \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T A \space dt$$

The dependence on frequency $\nu$ is purely due to the fact that in general, there is a distribution of EM waves with different intensity at different frequencies; it is purely classical. The spectral irradiance is essentially the irradiance for waves that have frequency between $\nu$ and $\nu+d \nu$.

Comment: This answer ignores the $\nu$ dependence in the question.

Comment: @G.Smith I have updated my answer in response to your comment.